# tensorflow model with keras and tensorflow_addons layer is not getting loaded

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have trained a model with keras layers and weight_normalization layer from tensorflow_addons. This is the model I trained and saved in tensorflow file format:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as tk
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((X_train.shape[1]-1,)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation="relu")),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1048, activation="relu")),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tfa.layers.WeightNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Dense(206, activation="sigmoid")),
    ])
```

(and it has no custom metrics)

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

# autosave best Model
best_model = ModelCheckpoint("model", monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max',verbose=0, save_best_only=True)

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy',
                          patience = 15,
                          mode = 'max',
                          verbose = 1,
                          restore_best_weights = True)

callbacks = [best_model, earlystop]

model.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer= 'Adam',metrics= ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_res, y_res, epochs=100, verbose= 2, validation_data=(X_val[X_val.columns[1:]],y_val[y_val.columns[1:]]), callbacks=callbacks)
```

But when I load the model it returns an error:

```
model = tk.models.load_model("../input/model")
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 2     return
> 3
> ----> 4 model = tk.models.load_model("../input/model-custom", custom_objects={'__inference_dense_layer_call_fn_1126407':f1})
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py
> in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, options)
> 185     if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):
> 186       loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
> --> 187       return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
> 188
> 189   raise IOError(
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py
> in load(path, compile, options)
> 119
> 120   model = tf_load.load_internal(
> --> 121       path, options=options, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
> 122
> 123   # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, loader_cls)
> 631       try:
> 632         loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
> --> 633                             ckpt_options)
> 634       except errors.NotFoundError as err:
> 635         raise FileNotFoundError(
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py
> in **init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 192     self._models_to_reconstruct = []
> 193
> --> 194     super(KerasObjectLoader, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
> 195
> 196     # Now that the node object has been fully loaded, and the checkpoint has
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in **init**(self, object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
> ckpt_options)
> 128       self._concrete_functions[name] = _WrapperFunction(concrete_function)
> 129
> --> 130     self._load_all()
> 131     self._restore_checkpoint()
> 132
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py
> in _load_all(self)
> 216
> 217     # Load all other nodes and functions.
> --> 218     super(KerasObjectLoader, self)._load_all()
> 219
> 220     # Finish setting up layers and models. See function docstring for more info.
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in _load_all(self)
> 139   def _load_all(self):
> 140     """Loads all nodes and functions from the SavedModel and their edges."""
> --> 141     self._load_nodes()
> 142     self._load_edges()
> 143     # TODO(b/124045874): There are limitations with functions whose captures
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in _load_nodes(self)
> 281         # interface.
> 282         continue
> --> 283       node, setter = self._recreate(proto, node_id)
> 284       nodes[node_id] = node
> 285       node_setters[node_id] = setter
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py
> in _recreate(self, proto, node_id)
> 237         obj._handle_name = proto.variable.name + ':0'  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> 238     else:
> --> 239       obj, setter = super(KerasObjectLoader, self)._recreate(proto, node_id)
> 240     return obj, setter
> 241
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in _recreate(self, proto, node_id)
> 391     if kind not in factory:
> 392       raise ValueError("Unknown SavedObject type: %r" % kind)
> --> 393     return factorykind
> 394
> 395   def _recreate_user_object(self, proto, node_id):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in ()
> 380             lambda: self._recreate_user_object(proto.user_object, node_id)),
> 381         "asset": lambda: self._recreate_asset(proto.asset),
> --> 382         "function": lambda: self._recreate_function(proto.function),
> 383         "bare_concrete_function": functools.partial(
> 384             self._recreate_bare_concrete_function,
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py
> in _recreate_function(self, proto)
> 419   def _recreate_function(self, proto):
> 420     return function_deserialization.recreate_function(
> --> 421         proto, self._concrete_functions), setattr
> 422
> 423   def _recreate_bare_concrete_function(self, proto):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/function_deserialization.py
> in recreate_function(saved_function, concrete_functions)
> 259   concrete_function_objects = []
> 260   for concrete_function_name in saved_function.concrete_functions:
> --> 261     concrete_function_objects.append(concrete_functions[concrete_function_name])
> 262
> 263   for cf in concrete_function_objects:
>
> KeyError: '__inference_dense_layer_call_fn_1126407'

Can you please help me load the model correctly.. Thanks

Comment: Please show us how you're saving and loading your model.

Comment: Yes I have added the codes for that too

Comment: @rayryeng     here is the model I was talking about kaggle.com/timothyalexjohn/moa-imbalanced-multi-label please download the model and try loading the model to tf.keras you will also get an error... Please help me understand the error and rectify it...Thank You

Comment: I tried (without model.fit) with recent TF/keras 2.7 and can load the model successfully. Can you share a toy dataset or update my [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jvishnuvardhan/1ec6f3735c3940a17bc7a74057df6360/untitled1124.ipynb). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have both `keras` and `tensorflow` installed separately; I have worked with `tfa` and never had problems with regard to such a loading matter;

In fact, here you import everything via `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as tk
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

But here you load the callbacks via plain `keras`:

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
```

In order to first ensure that you do have a loading model problem situation, please make sure that every import is done via `tensorflow.keras` (I expect the problem to disappear altogether once you do this).

Replace

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
```

with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
```

To sum up, retrain from scratch with the new imports (all from `tensorflow.keras`) and then check if the problem is reproduced.

Comment: This time a new layer number is showing up: "__inference_dense_layer_call_fn_358721" 
Should I add the class for tensorflow_addons layer as custom layer?
Can you please help me with code if that is required as I don't know how to add custom metrics or custom layers.  [I am using it in Kaggle Environment with preference set to "Latest"]

Comment: here is the model i was talking about  https://www.kaggle.com/timothyalexjohn/moa-imbalanced-multi-label   
please download the model and try loading the model to tf.keras  you willalso get an error... Please help me understand the error and rectify it...Thank You